# Angle of rotation from complex eigenvalues of Rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations

The complex eigenvalues of a Rotation matrix are $e^{-i\theta}$ and $e^{i\theta}$. Corresponding to these we get complex eigenvectors.

We know that the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue 1 is the axis of rotation. How to prove that the $\theta$ from complex eigenvalues is the angle of rotation.

Comparing it with some Rotation matrix for rotation about x,y or z axis is easy, but how to conclude this for a generic R belonging to SO(3).

Answer (score 3):

We know that a rotation matrix has real entries:
$${ \bf R_\theta } = \left[\begin{array}{rr} \cos(\theta) &-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{array}\right] =  /a = \cos(\theta), b = \sin(\theta)/ = \left[\begin{array}{rr} a &-b\\b&a\end{array}\right]$$

Now consider
$$|{\bf R_\theta} - \lambda {\bf I}| = (a-\lambda)^2+b^2 = 0$$
Expand to find a polynomial in $\lambda$ with real coefficients. Such a polynomial must have pairs of complex conjugate roots. We could just factor directly using the conjugacy rule $x^2-y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$:

$$(a+bi - \lambda)(a-bi-\lambda) = 0$$

And we see the roots are $\lambda = a \pm bi=  \cos(\theta) \pm i \sin(\theta)$

Finally since sin is odd, this means we can put the signs inside, altering only the sign of sine:

$\lambda = \cos(\theta) \pm i \sin(\theta) = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\mp \theta)$

So far is enough to show a 2D rotation matrix eigenvalues has the properties you sought. A 3D rotation is just a shift of basis to the plane of rotation and the axis of rotation. The vector corresponding to the axis is identity and the vectors in the plane are rotated. As this is a direct sum it has the eigenvalues of the elements of the direct sum, so it "inherits" the eigenvalues from it's 2D and 1D components.

---

You might argue that because the eigenvalues have plus and minus for the imaginary part we don't know which one to choose. But you can simply read from the rotation matrix itself where the minus sign of the sine is to figure out the orientation of the rotation.

Comment: However, it appears that the eigenvalue method has [significant limitations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqQ64.png), Or maybe I didn't fully understand your this answer?

Comment: @mayi You can add or subtract any number of $2\pi$ and it will be the same. A rotation matrix doesn't count the number of full revolutions we turn, only the relative direction our nose ends up in. If you do a 360 the end result will be pointing in same direction as you started.

Comment: Oh no. Could you look carefully at my screenshots? please. My `π/4`,`5π/4` and `7π/4` all less than `2π`

Comment: @mayi : I don't know which software you use or what those values written are supposed to represent. Well yes plus or minus depends on which direction you rotate. But to prove my point $5\pi/4 -- 3\pi/4 = 2\pi$ and $7\pi/4 -- \pi/4 = 2\pi$. There is a limit in rotation matrices that we don't know if we rotate $1/4$ of a revolution one way or $3/4$ the other way.

Comment: The software is called [Wolfram Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), but it doesn't matter. Because you solve the eigenvalues manually and then the arg is the same. Also, I'm not saying that there are limitations to the rotation matrix, but that there are limitations to solving the rotation angle of the rotation matrix by eigenvalues method. Since we don't know the direction of rotation, we don't know the sign of the angle either.

Comment: @mayi : Yes you will have this information if you do an eigenvalue decomposition, but you need to look at the eigenvectors as well. If you align eigenvectors with real numbers you will be able to determine the correct direction. This problem is automatically solved if you use a numerical method over an algebraically closed field and start with real numbers.

Comment: Just pick eigenvector [1;i] and you will be getting the eigenvalue corresponding to the sign of the upper right sine.

Comment: Oh, yes, [you are right this time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpmeE.png). But I don't know the mathematical principle here. Could you parse it in your post? Our current comments are a bit too long and not very user-friendly

Comment: @mayi there is no advanced mathematical principle. You can just look at the sign. Which of the sine is negative and which is positive.

Comment: I'm sorry. It is true that the direction of rotation can be determined by the sign of sine as [your reminder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1d8o.jpg), but what does this have to do with choosing $(i;1)$?

Comment: @mayi it is much simpler. It makes no sense to make this thread any more convoluted. It has taken too much time already.

Comment: Oh, no. You're my hero. You've provided enough information to [solve this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfvVk.png). I've searched many tutorials and almost none of them make this clear, [like here](http://www.sharetechnote.com/html/Handbook_EngMath_Matrix_Det_Eig_Graphical.html). But you've pretty much solved the problem. Cut out the communication process above and leave a concise conclusion, which will save valuable time for the users that follow. They will remember you. :)

Comment: Hmm. If they will remember me it's probably not for this conclusion..

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $e^{i\theta}\neq e^{-i\theta}$. I leave to you the case $e^{i\theta}=e^{-i\theta}$.

Let $v=v_1+iv_2$ be a column vector of $\mathbb{C}^3$ such that $Rv=e^{i\theta}v$, where $v_1,v_2\in\mathbb{R^3}$ (Prove that $v_1\neq 0$ and $v_2\neq 0$). Let $v^t$ be its transpose.

Now, $R^tR=Id$ then $v=R^tRv=e^{i\theta}R^tv$. So $R^tv=e^{-i\theta}$.

Next, $e^{i\theta}v^tv=v^tRv=(v^tRv)^t=v^tR^tv=e^{-i\theta}v^tv$.

Since $e^{i\theta}\neq e^{-i\theta}$ then $0=v^tv=|v_1|^2-|v_2|^2+i2(v_2^tv_1)$. So $|v_1|=|v_2|$ and $v_1\perp v_2$.
Without loss of generality assume $|v_1|=|v_2|=1$.

Now, $R(v_1)+iR(v_2)=R(v_1+iv_2)=(cos(\theta)+isin(\theta))(v_1+iv_2)=$ $(cos(\theta)v_1-sin(\theta) v_2)+i(sin(\theta) v_1+cos(\theta)v_2)$.

So $R(v_1)=(cos(\theta)v_1-sin(\theta) v_2)$ and R$(v_2)=(sin(\theta) v_1+cos(\theta)v_2)$.

Let $W$ be the plane generated by $v_1,v_2$.

Finally, the matrix of the restriction of R to $W$ relative to the orthonormal basis $v_1,v_2$ is $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
cos(\theta) & sin(\theta) \\
-sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)  
\end{array}\right) $.

Answer (score 0):

The trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues, therefore
$$\eqalign{
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\tr{\operatorname{Tr}}
\tr(R)
 &= \l_1+\l_2+\l_3 \\
 &= \o+e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta} \\
 &= \o + 2\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}\right) \\
 &= \o + 2\cos(\theta) \\
}$$
If $\theta=2n\pi,$ then all of the eigenvalues equal $\o$ and $R=I.$

Squaring the matrix preserves the axis of rotation, but **doubles** the angle of rotation
$$\eqalign{
\tr(R^2)
 &= \l_1^2+\l_2^2+\l_3^2 \\
 &= \o+e^{i2\theta}+e^{-i2\theta} \\
 &= \o + 2\left(\frac{e^{i2\theta}+e^{-i2\theta}}{2}\right) \\
 &= \o + 2\cos(2\theta) \\
}$$
Similarly, raising the rotation matrix to the $k^{th}$ power yields
$$\tr(R^k) = \o + 2\cos(k\theta) \qquad\quad $$
Thus the $\theta$ which appears in the eigenvalues **behaves** like the angle of rotation.